# Plotting graph against row number in Excel

Tags: excel

I have plotted a graph in excel from B8 to B45. But, it plots the values starting from 1 along the x-axis. I want to make sure B8 to B45 are plotted against their original row numbers i.e. from 8-45 while the numbers with no data ex: 1-7 are 0. Would appreciatre any suggestions.

Graph obtained:

[image]

Graph required to be obtained (Expected):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a column (i.e. between col A and col B) and populate with the row numbers (1, 2, 3...45). You may have to do that manually, or fill in the first few numbers then double click on the autofill toggle on the bottom right corner of the cell.

Then set this newly column as the X value for the chart.

Answer (score 0):

On your graph click on "chart filters" then under categories, deselect the data 1-7 that are unwanted.

Is this what you wanted?